# Sharing a configuration file between Python and a React project created with create-react-app

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs

I need to share a configuration file between Python and React code - I could use JSON, which is easy to import into each, but I'd prefer to be able to add comments, turn parts on and off, etc.

What is a good way of doing something like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been trying out [HJSON (human-readable JSON)](http://hjson.org), but bundling a text file like HJSON into the React build doesn't work AFAIK without ejecting create-react-app and modifying the webpack config to use [raw-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/raw-loader), or using [react-app-rewired](https://github.com/timarney/react-app-rewired) to do something similar.

I wound up using [react-app-rewired](https://github.com/timarney/react-app-rewired) -

First add these libraries to the React project -

```
yarn add react-app-rewired
yarn add hjson
yarn add hjson-loader
```

Then add a `config-overrides.js` file to the top level of the React project - this will modify the webpack config on the fly -

```js
const { getLoader } = require('react-app-rewired');

function rewireAddHjson(config, env, options = {}) {
  const hjsonExtension = /\.hjson$/;
  const excludeRule = getLoader(config.module.rules, rule => rule.exclude);
  excludeRule.exclude.push(hjsonExtension);
  const hjsonRule = {
    test: hjsonExtension,
    loader: 'hjson-loader',
  };
  config.module.rules.push(hjsonRule);
  return config;
}

module.exports = function override(config, env) {
  config = rewireAddHjson(config, env);
  return config;
};
```

and in `package.json` replace "react-scripts" with "react-app-rewired":

```
"scripts": {
-   "start": "react-scripts start",
-   "build": "react-scripts build",
-   "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
+   "start": "react-app-rewired start",
+   "build": "react-app-rewired build",
+   "test": "react-app-rewired test --env=jsdom"
}
```

Then in Python you can say

```
import hjson
with open('app/client/src/assets/options.hjson') as f:
    options = hjson.load(f)
```

and in React can say

```js
import options from '../assets/options.hjson'; // a json object
```