# How do you use HJSON with Jest in a create-react-app project?

Tags: javascript, jestjs, hjson

I'm using [HJSON](http://hjson.org/) in a create-react-app project (see answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47487014/sharing-a-configuration-file-between-python-and-a-react-project-created-with-cre/47487015#47487015)), but Jest doesn't use the same webpack configuration, so fails to import HJSON properly - e.g.

```
import options from '../assets/options.hjson';
```

just sets `options` to the string '../assets/options.hjson'.

So how can you import an HJSON file using Jest?

Answer (score 1):

You need to make a transformer module for Jest to convert the HJSON to JSON - see the docs [here](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/configuration.html#transform-object-string-string).

Make a file `jest-hjson-transformer.js` in your root directory with

```
const hjson = require('hjson');

function process(src, path, config, transformOptions) {
  const json = hjson.parse(src);
  const jsonStr = JSON.stringify(json, null, 2);
  const out = `module.exports = ${jsonStr}`;
  return out;
}
exports.process = process;
```

And in your `package.json`,

```
  "jest": {
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "jsx",
      "hjson"
    ],
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.hjson$": "<rootDir>/jest-hjson-transformer.js"
    }
  },
```